# Is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$, $0 < a_n < 1$?

Tags: calculus

Claim: Suppose that $0 < a_n < 1$, then $\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$.

With additional conditions, e.g., $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$, the claim is true. But I was wondering if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$ is needed. I failed to find a counter example to disprove the original claim, and would like some help.

Comment: What about the sequence $1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, ...$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(b_n)$ be any strictly decreasing sequence that tends to $1$, and define $a_n=b_{n+1}/b_n$.

Then $0<a_n<1$ for all $n$, but $\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1/b_1$.

Also, $a_n\rightarrow 1$, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$. So your additional condition doesn't make the claim true. Did you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$? That would work, trivially, because it means that $a_n\rightarrow0$.